# Confirm Dialog Opens onClick for All Items on Action Bar

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Hello I am new to android, I have several items on my action bar and also a logout icon/button.  Now when the user clicks on the logout button it should display a confirm dialog and go back to the login screen if the user clicks "Yes".

I have managed to do this, however I have noticed that the confirm dialog now displays for all items I click not just the logout.

This is my code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {

            case R.id.action_open_invoices:
                Intent i = new Intent(context, InvoicesActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            case R.id.action_synchronize:
                // Start Updater Service
                Intent updaterService = new Intent(context, UpdaterService.class);
                startService(updaterService);

            case R.id.action_logout:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                builder.setTitle("Confirm");
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");

                builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        settings.edit().remove("Token").commit();

                        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(loginIntent);

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Do nothing
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case R.id.action_open_invoices:
            Intent i = new Intent(context, InvoicesActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
       break;
```

Use break statement